# Base quicksync parameters for realtime streaming

Tags: c++, video-streaming, webrtc, intel, encoder

I've wrote quicksync encoder hardware implementation for realtime streaming. Everything works fine, however now I got stuck on encoder parametrization. Docs from Intel are very poor and non-specific. I've read:

- SDK API Reference Manual
- Intel Media Developer's Guide(rev. 2017)

I've also tried to follow the NVENC guidelines(I did same for Nvidia a while ago and everything works fine) but no luck here either.

So far with:

```
    m_mfxEncParams.IOPattern = MFX_IOPATTERN_IN_VIDEO_MEMORY;

    m_mfxEncParams.AsyncDepth = 4;

    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.TargetKbps = my_target_bps_ / 1000;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.MaxKbps = 0;
    //m_mfxEncParams.mfx.InitialDelayInKB = 0;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.BufferSizeInKB = my_width_ * my_height_ * 1.5;

    //FRAME INFO PARAMS
    ConvertFrameRate(30, &m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.FrameRateExtN, &m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.FrameRateExtD);

    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.FourCC = MFX_FOURCC_NV12;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.ChromaFormat = MFX_CHROMAFORMAT_YUV420;

    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.PicStruct = MFX_PICSTRUCT_PROGRESSIVE;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.Shift = 0;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.CropX = 0;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.CropY = 0;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.CropW = my_width_;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.CropH = my_height_;

    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.Width = MSDK_ALIGN16(width_);
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.Height =
        (MFX_PICSTRUCT_PROGRESSIVE == m_mfxEncParams.mfx.FrameInfo.PicStruct)
        ? MSDK_ALIGN16(height_)
        : MSDK_ALIGN32(height_);

    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.CodecId = MFX_CODEC_AVC;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.CodecProfile = MFX_PROFILE_AVC_BASELINE;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.CodecLevel = 0;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.GopPicSize = 0;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.GopRefDist = 1;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.GopOptFlag = MFX_GOP_STRICT;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.IdrInterval = 0;

    //TRADEOF BETWEEN QUALITY AND SPEED
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.TargetUsage = MFX_TARGETUSAGE_BALANCED;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.RateControlMethod = MFX_RATECONTROL_CBR;


    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.NumSlice = 0;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.NumRefFrame = 0;
    m_mfxEncParams.mfx.EncodedOrder = 0; // binary flag, 0 signals encoder to take frames in display order
    //CODING OPTION 2
    auto codingOption2 = m_mfxEncParams.AddExtBuffer<mfxExtCodingOption2>();

    codingOption2->LookAheadDepth = 0;
    codingOption2->MaxSliceSize = 0;
    codingOption2->MaxFrameSize = 0;
    codingOption2->BRefType = MFX_B_REF_OFF;

    codingOption2->ExtBRC = 0;

    codingOption2->IntRefType = 0;
    codingOption2->IntRefCycleSize = 0;
    codingOption2->IntRefQPDelta = 0;
    codingOption2->AdaptiveI = 0;
    codingOption2->AdaptiveB = 0;
```

Right now for FullHD I've got 20 FPS of really low quality with bitrate around 2mb/s(peak, static is around 800kb/s), while for FullHD on Nvidia I've got 40 FPS of really quality image with bitrate around 1.3mb/s(peak, static is around 300kb/s)

I need some kind of starting point settings for real-time streaming with QuickSync or at least some extra literature on that subject.

EDIT: I should specify. That hardware's implementation sole purpose is to encode image to send to browser via webrtc. That is why I use Baseline profile. I know in theory chromium can decode Main and High profiles, however for now I just want to stay within borders of officially supported Baseline profile(same profile which I use with NVENC).